# c# Отправка смс на номер телефона при помощи Twilio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Создала *консольное приложение(.NET CORE)*. Необходимо отправить смс на номер телефона при помощи Twilio

Скачала twilio в visual studio

[image: twilio]

Зарегистрировалась на Twilio, взяла пробный номер, все прошло успешно.
На сайте был предложен готовый код для тестирования отправки смс.

```
using System;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/console
        // and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
        string accountSid = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AC03798a1882921c7f150d85a1f99*****");
        string authToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("2f292189645ecf6e4c5e75cd********");

        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var message = MessageResource.Create(
            body: "Hello, Alina from c# lesson",
            from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+12059473***"),
            to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+77473788***")
        );

        Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
    }
}
```

Здесь необходимо было изменить accountSid и authToken(что я и сделала). А также поменять номера(откуда и куда)

Однако при запуске мне выдается ошибка:
[image: ошибка]

С чем это может быть связано? Может не тот Twilio скачала? Или в коде ошибки?

> TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken); //15 line

Comment: Ну вам ведь ошибка говорит, что не так - приложение уже используется (либо вы его держите открытым, либо оно зависло у вас в процессах).

Comment: Вы серьезно, решили кардинально изменить суть вопроса? Так не делается, ибо вот что мой комментарий выше, это просто в пустоту? Ок... Вас `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` не смущает?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  А что именно Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Вы когда пишете `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(`, что просит ввести студия внутри скобок? Я подскажу `string variable`, а сам метод как называется? `Get Environment` (ключевое слово `GET`). Логически приходим к выводу, что этот метод получает некое значение по названию, а если быть точнее, то в любой OS есть так называемые `переменные среды`, которые задаются до запуска приложения как `значение=ключ`. То есть, вы просите у OS переменную среды, название которой `AC03798a188...`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Т.е. если я создам переменную, куда занесу значение AC03798a188 и передам эту переменную в Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable() - это будет правильно?

Comment: либо просто `string accountSid = "ваш ключ"`, без каких-либо `GetEnvironmentVariable()`, но это вы захардкорите ключ в коде, что не есть хорошо.